# Can't seem to mutate columns using variable names

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to perform some programmatic changes to a large tibble/data frame in R. The suggestion through the [`dplyr` programming vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) suggests to use a glue-like syntax (like `{{`...`}}`) together with `:=`. However, neither of the examples below result in what I want.

```
library(tidyverse)

some_var <- 'a'
df <- tibble(
  !!'a' := 1:3,
  Sum := !!some_var # <--- should yield 1:3 but yields c('a', 'a', 'a')
)

some_var <- 'b'
df <- tibble(
  !!'a' := 1:3,
  Sum := a
) %>% mutate(
  b = 1:3,
  Sum := Sum + !!some_var # <--- should yield 1:3 + 1:3 = c(2, 4, 6), but fails
)
```

The second example is different from the first in that the error seems to group `Sum` and `!!some_var` into a single column called `` `Sum + 'b'` ``:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `Sum`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `Sum` is `Sum + "b"`.
```

How can I achieve my desired result using the variable names (`some_var`) above?

Comment: If you have a string, use the `.data` pronoun. For example `Sum = .data[[some_var]]` and `Sum := Sum + .data[[some_var]]`. The `!!` expects symbols, not strings. This was included in the "Indirection" section of the dplyr programming guide you linked to.

Comment: @MrFlick: Woah! That slipped my reading and is now clear. Thanks!